# Does contact with metal surfaces reduce the vitamin levels of vegetables?

Tags: nutrition, vitamins, vegetables

I have heard that cutting or grating vegetables with metal tools somehow reduces the vitamin content (or as it is sometimes stated "it kills the vitamins"). There are also commercials, which advocate glass or ceramic tools for preserving vitamins.

I have seen similar claims on the Internet (e.g., provided by @ChrisW: [How to keep the vitamins in the food – STEEL KNIFES DESTROY VITAMINS](http://mumteaching.com/2009/07/13/how-to-keep-the-vitamins-in-the-food-steel-knifes-destroy-vitamins/)), but I couldn't find any scientific studies.

Are vitamins in food significantly affected by contact with metal utensils?

Comment: One example of the claim: [How to keep the vitamins in the food – STEEL KNIFES DESTROY VITAMINS](http://mumteaching.com/2009/07/13/how-to-keep-the-vitamins-in-the-food-steel-knifes-destroy-vitamins/)

Comment: Related claim is that *sharp* knives are better, since vitamins A and C are ["diminished when vegetable tissues are bruised"](http://www.2020tech.com/health/health02.html). Since one common selling point for glass/ceramic knives is that they don't dull as quickly as metal, it could be related to that.

Comment: It is a good idea to include an example of the claim in the question (copy the one from @chrisW's comment if you like.)

Comment: @ChrisW: I'm still laughing at the use of a "potato battery" to prove... err... "Electricity! I knew it all along!"

Comment: @Oddthinking, I was just laughing at that myself.